# HTML5 show hidden form elements after submitting and showing the required tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have to hide some elements within a  from a form. So these fields are required. This  is only shown if you click on a specific button. How can I show the  if the required-fields are not set after klick the submit button?

the form is sending via jquery

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).is(".send")) {
      alert("Have you entered all Information?");
      $("#standardform").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

the  is following:

```
<div class="infos"></div>
            <div class="infoform form">
                    <select name="test" required>
                        <option value="">Please select</option>
                        <option value="jubi">1</option>
                        <option value="geb">2</option>
                        <option value="bef">3r</option>
                    </select>
                        <input class="required" type="radio" id="indoor" name="ort" value="indoor" required /><label for="indoor"> Indoor</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="outdoor" name="ort" value="outdoor" /><label for="outdoor"> Outdoor</label>
                    </section>
                        <textarea id="text"></textarea>
                        Name: <input type="text" id="name" required /><br />
                        E-Mail:<input type="email" id="email" required /><br /><br />
                </div>
            </div>
```

so the class infos is shown alwas, and if you click on it the class infoform is shown. I want to make infoform visible if a field is not set and the message "You have to fill out this field" should be shown there.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Create on your form an `onsubmit` event ?

Comment: But what should I take there... there is not only the one infoform, there are more like this..

Comment: Create a function that checks what you required. Like if the field is empty, then send an alert and `return false;` which will prevent the form to be sent. You can check if there are enough characters, or everything you want. Just return true when everything is correct

Comment: Do you want to display alert when `required` input is empty?

Comment: @Mohammad No, I want to show <div class="infoform> if required input is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html `required` attribute to do this work. When `button` clicked, select every element that has `required` attribute. You can use css `:required` selector to select required element(input, textarea, select). After selecting elements, check value of selected element and if value is empty, alert displaying.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    var hasEmpty = false;
    $("*:required").each(function(index, element){
        value = $(element).val();
        if (value == "")
            hasEmpty = true;
    });
    if (hasEmpty)
        alert("Form is incomplete.");
    else {
        $(".infoform").hide();
        alert("Form is complete.");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infoform">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label>Other info</label>
        <textarea name="info" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label>Age</label>
        <select name="age" required>
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="age1">10-20</option>
            <option value="age2">21-30</option>
            <option value="age2">31-40</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <button>Check values</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is not what I am searching for. I want to show an hidden form if it is incomplete.

Comment: @JohnHSmith How filled value of inputs?

Comment: you could open them if you klick the <div class="infos"> and close with another button. Both via jquery.

Comment: @JohnHSmith `I want to show an hidden form if it is incomplete`. See https://jsfiddle.net/0tr549L5/1/

Comment: @JohnHSmith If your problem doesn't solve, i change my answer?

Comment: I see it, changed my site and it works. But I want to show the exclamation-mark with "Please fill out this field". How can I do this too?

Comment: @JohnHSmith If element has `required` attribute and be inside `<form>`, when submit of form, message displaying.

Comment: Yeah this is my Opinion too, but it is NOT shown! the <div class="infoform> is shown, but not the message.

Comment: Oh okay, the submit button too! Thank you!